# .htacess Rewrite URL to Redirect certain request to subdmian

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect to the mobile version of the website when the request is made from Ios Browser  and Successfully able to do it with following rule

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone|iPod
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(reset) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^$ https://m.mydoamin1.com [L,R=302]
```

But I don't want to hard code my domain name here since my website is accessible from 2 domains

For Example

- mydomain1.com shud redirect to m.mydomain1.com
- mydomain2.com shud redirect to m.mydomain2.com

I'm trying to archive this with a single rule-but this doesn't work

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone|iPod
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(reset) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^$ https://m.{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Does "doesn't work" materialize in a specific outcome? And why `REQUEST_URI` instead of `SERVER_NAME`. And why `{…` instead of `%{…`?

Comment: @mario Can please you provide the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone|iPod [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !reset [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://m.%1 [L,R=301]
```

Condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]` will match `mydomain1.com` or `www.mydomain1.com` but will always grab `mydomain1.com` in capture group #1 which is used in `RewriteRule` as `%1`.